# xsl <choose>: How to select a following-sibling with a certain child?

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the following fragment of a dictionary entry:

```
<entry>
      <form>
        <orth></orth>
        <orth></orth>       
      </form>
      <form>
        <note></note>
        <orth></orth>
      </form>
</entry>
```

With xsl `<choose>` I want to select `<form>` only when the following `<form>` has `<note>` as a child. I tried

```
<xsl:template match="tei:form">
  <xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][name()='form' and child='note']">
      <xsl:apply-templates/><text>\ </text>
    </xsl:when>

  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

But this does not work. How should I correctly address `<form>` with `<note>` as child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing. `xsl:choose` does not select anything.

If you want to use `xsl:choose` in the context of `form` - IOW, you want to process **all** `form` elements and choose which code should be executed based on the existence of `note` in the immediately following sibling - try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="form">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::form[1]/note">
            <!-- DO SOMETHING -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- DO SOMETHING ELSE -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

In order to process **only** the form elements that satisfy the condition, try instead:

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
    <!-- ... -->
    <xsl:for-each select="form[following-sibling::form[1]/note]">
        <!-- DO SOMETHING -->
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Of course, if the qualified name is actually `tei:form`, as suggested by the match pattern in the supplied code, then this should be `following-sibling::tei:form[1]/tei:note`

Comment: Yes, I want to process all form elements. So the first solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to apply templates to all of your `form` elements, then you can avoid the use of conditional instrucctions and just use patterns like:

```
<xsl:template match="form">
    <!-- General case -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="form[following-sibling::form[1]/note]">
    <!-- Particular case -->
</xsl:template>
```

**Do note**: these patterns have different [default priority](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#conflict), thus the template to apply is perfectly determinded.